# Find minimum and show the area/values around it

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to find a minimum in a very long time series, but instead of show the whole series with 2000 points, or only 1 line, I want to show the *20 rows with the `profit` value before and after the minimum*,

result example :

```
company date_num, profit  min
A       EPOCH     4       2
A       EPOCH     2       2     # show 10 results before and after 2, for A.
A       EPOCH     16      2
C       EPOCH     9       9
C       EPOCH     11      9
```

So, per company, find the minimum, then print the "area" around the minimum, say 10 results before and after.

Goal is to print the area of the minimum with a line that show minimum.

This gives me a single line result:

```
WITH BS AS (
SELECT date_num, company,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY company ORDER BY profit desc) as rn
FROM history
WHERE company in ['a','b','c']
)
SELECT date_num, company
FROM BS
WHERE rn = 1
```

**EDIT**:

To clarify, thanks to the comments here, if minimum 2 was on August 15, i want to show all results between 10-20th August.
`date_time` is a number date which show the date in days as `int` number in seconds. (epoch)

Comment: What do you mean by *before* and *after* - if you get the minimum profit there is no *before* unless you define an ordering you aren't showing here.

Comment: i mean the profit values before and after the minimum.. to make it easy for people to see the full area of he minimum.\

Comment: *Before* implies some ordering, eg a date column, which is not shown in your sample data.

Comment: @baltiturg: I think you have misunderstood what Stu says. The minimum for company A is profit = 2. After that minimum there is profit = 4 and then profit =16. But how can there be anything *before* the minimum? The word "minimum" implies that there is nothing before it.

Comment: @Stu I think you can clearly see a date column in my example called date_num, and have EPOCH dates....

Comment: @ThorstenKettner thanks, this is a time series, so "before" imply time. if the minimum was on 15 August, i wan to show 10-20 August profit values. I edited question.

Comment: Voted to close. @baltiturg, the minimum effort from your side would have been to supply a reasonable data sample, large enough, containing all the relevant data ("EPOCH" is not enough) and references the edge cases (E.g. the minimum value occurs multiple times), as well as the expected result set.

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz dudu your decision is ridicules, this question is beautiful and clear, show effort, and i even edited it. You sound like a not fair person. Good luck מר דודו מרקוביץ , i got a good answer, which you probably couldn't provide.

Comment: @baltiturg, the close vote is for this specific post, not for you. I explained exactly what is wrong with this post.

Comment: your explanation is not accepted, i did accepted the answer though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two steps:

- find the minimum rows
- find their surrounding rows

For this, determine the minimum profit with `MIN OVER` and also number the rows with `ROW_NUMBER`. Thus you can then select all rows the row number of which is not farther away than 10 from the minimum rows' row number.

```
WITH bs AS
(
  SELECT 
    company, date_num, profit,
    MIN(profit) OVER (PARTITION BY company) AS min_profit,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY company ORDER BY date_num) AS rn
  FROM history
  WHERE company IN ('A', 'B', 'C')
)
SELECT company, date_num, profit
FROM bs
WHERE EXISTS
(
  SELECT NULL
  FROM bs bsmin
  WHERE bsmin.profit = bsmin.min_profit
  AND bsmin.company = bs.company
  AND ABS(bs.rn - bsmin.rn) <= 10
)
ORDER BY company, date_num;
```

Comment: thanks a lot ! you somehow always give the best answer. i just don't understand what's people's problem with such a question, i spent so much time and posted a clear question. Not sure what is wrong with some programmers temperament.

Comment: Well, you got us confused a lot by putting the string 'EPOCH' in your sample data. Your request would be much easier to understand if you put different numbers in there like in your real data. I, too, think that at the time David voted to close, your edit had made the request clear enough. But please understand that we do need people who look at requests and decide to close them. Otherwise people would get a lot of garbage when they google their issue. Sometimes these decisions are wrong, but don't take this personal. This just happens now and then.

Comment: thanks, i do think that for a few years (and SO knows it) those "moderators" caused many good people to leave, due to their harsh attitude. It feels like a pool of sharks that swim around and nobody wants to get in anymore. When I post a question i am always scared if i did something wrong. This is not how the internet should be, it feels more like an army, too many harsh rules. They could keep the order in other ways, not by "downvoting" people. It is such a robotic unhealthy inhuman approach.

Comment: regarding the answer, can you please explain what bsmin.company = bs.company means? did you mean bsmin.company? also if there are 2 minimums it picks one right?

Comment: I meant `bsmin.company = bs.company`, i.e. the subquery looks at rows that match the company of the main query. And no, all minimum rows are considered. If there are two rows with profit 2 for company A, then both dates and their surrounding rows get selected.

Comment: thank you, by the way, as a moderator, i can tell you now that the website is automatically blocking me from posting due to these 2 downvotes, so there you go, one user less because the rules+people's approach